# How to pass functions as props to React Custom Modal?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-props, react-modal

I am implementing a login page in React.
Currently, the login page is implemented in Modal with the React-Modal library.
When the login button is pressed in the login page, data is transmitted to the newly created Custom Modal as props to display a notification window.
But openmodalState doesn't work.
I would like to know how to solve it.

```
function login(props : Iprops) {
  
  const {setopenmodal, openmodal} = props

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [Opnemotal,setOpenmodal] = useState(false) // state to pass to custom modal
  

  const login = async() => {
    dispatch(LoginHandler(Email, Password, setopenmodal, setOpenmodal))
  }

  

  const CloseModal = () => {
    setOpenmodal(false)
  }

  


  return (
    <div style = {{opacity : openmodal ? '1' : '0', transform : openmodal ? 'translate(0vh)' : 'translate(-100vh)'}}>
      <div className="login">
              <h1>로그인</h1>
          <button onClick = {login}>로그인</button>
          <button>아이디/비밀번호 찾기</button>
        </div>
      </div>
<Modal open = {Opnemotal} close = {CloseModal} header = {openmodal ? "비밀번호를 확인해주시기 바랍니다" : "로그인이 완료되었습니다"}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default login;
```

This part is the login part to Redux Action

```
export const LoginHandler = (Email : string, Password : string, setopenmodal : any, ResModal : any) => {
    return async(dispatch : Dispatch<Action>) => {
        await axios.post('/api/authenticate',{
            email : Email,
            password : Password
        })
        .then((response) => {
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data)
            console.log(response)
            dispatch({
                type : ActionType.LOGIN_USER,
                payload : response.data
            })
        })
        .then(() => {
            setopenmodal(false)
            ResModal(false)
        })
    }
}
```

Here is my custom modal

```
interface IProps {
    open : boolean,
    confirm? : boolean,
    close : Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>,
    header : string,
    children? : React.ReactNode
}

function Modal(props : IProps) {

    const {open, close, header} = props

    return (
         // 모달이 열릴때 openModal 클래스가 생성된다.
         <div className={ open ? 'openModal modal' : 'modal' }>
         { open ? (  
             <section>
                 <header>
                     {header}
                     <button className="close" onClick={() => close}> &times; </button>
                 </header>
                 <main>
                     {props.children}
                 </main>
                 <footer>
                     <button className="close" onClick={() => close}> close </button>
                 </footer>
             </section>
         ) : null }
     </div>
    )
}
```

It seems that the values ​​are not passed properly as props.

There are no errors and nothing happens.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Why don't you export your`Modal`?

Answer (score 3):

Because you don't call props `close`. just update like this:

```
onClick={() => close()}
```

or

```
onClick={close}
```